# Rename headers in Pandas aggreate function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use aggregate to apply mutiple functions to my dataframe,

and it turns out that, it will add another row to indicate the name of the functions,

I'm wondering if there's any way to rename the headers in advanced, so that I will not have the extra row

```
    feature_setup = {'A':['min','max','mean','std','sum'] , 
                 'B': ['min','max','mean','std','sum'], 
                 'C': ['sum'],
                 'D': ['sum']}
features = ['A','B,'C','D']
dataframe = df[features].rolling(w_size).agg(feature_setup)
```

and my result dataframe is like

```
     A    B    C    D   A    B    A     B   A    B
0  min  max  sum  sum  mean mean  std  std  sum sum
1   0    0    0    0    0    0      0   0    0    0
2  ....
```

is there any way to rename headers in advance, or to combine row 0 and header ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the multiindex columns into string based columns like

```
x = df[features].rolling(2).agg(feature_setup)
x.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in x]
```

Columns will be

```
A_min   A_max   A_mean  A_std   A_sum   B_min   B_max   B_mean  B_std   B_sum   C_sum
```